# Who needs ESTA?

Tags: uk, us-citizens, esta

I'm a U.S. citizen, about to go from Boston to London.  I thought ESTA was for non-citizens entering USA.  But the airline shows me a web page saying I must have it to go to **or from** USA **or UK**.  And not a word to suggest that it doesn't apply to all nationalities.

The application form suggests that my first thought was correct and that I don't need it.  Since my first leg to BOS boards forty hours from now, this is a disturbing development.

Am I right (not needed) or are they right (I'm in trouble)?

UPDATE: Since I posted the question, they roamed the word "from" and it now says "Visa Waiver Program
When travelling to the USA,United Kingdom, all passengers eligible to travel under the Visa Waiver Program must apply for an Electronic System Travel Authorisation (ESTA). Read more"

Clicking on "read more" says a lot about both USA and UK.

Comment: Can you link the airline's webpage (or take a screenshot and post that), because that information seems rather wrong indeed, and I'm curious how exactly they've phrased it.

Comment: Is it possible you made a mistake on an earlier screen when entering your nationality / passport info?

Comment: Why do you keep quoting a few words at a time from a website without actually revealing a link to it?

Comment: Because the URI has parameters containing private info.  And the rest of the page is completely irrelevant to the topic.  Only that part relates to ESTA.  What do you mean by "keep"?  If you are "following" me, you know that I frequently paste URIs.

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate, and the answers there agree with here (and with what I thought originally).  I wish this app didn't make it so hard to find duplicates.  Feel free to close.

Comment: @WGroleau Could you please dial down the paranoia just a tad? As Henning pointed out, you posted your question, without providing a link. You then edited it (update) and again, no link. That is all he means by his 'keep'. You don't have to post the URI, but a link to, or heck, even the name of the airline, might help, ya think?

Comment: Not much paranoia here.  Just puzzled by the word "keep" for a _single_ quote.  Airline is Norwegian.

Comment: For example, you're STILL not disclosing where the "read more" link that you claim "says at lot about both US and UK" takes you -- even though it is difficult to imagine that such a link would include personal information.

Comment: I already told you why. Your choice to believe it or not.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need ESTA. You can almost certainly get in the UK without a visa (depending on the nature of your trip) and you can just go to the US citizen line when you return to the US.